# Table updating in SQL with VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm updating my table, but I don't know why doesn't work. I trace the program and understand that the code will run, but the table won't be updated.

```
Dim commandf3 As New SqlCommand("Update Barcode set Tedad=@Tedad,Vazn=@Vazn,Ojrat=@Ojrat,Availability=@Availability where Onvan=@Onvan", connection)
commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Onvan", txtM.Text)
commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tedad", tedadjadid)
commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vazn", vaznjadid)
commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ojrat", ojratjadid)
commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Availability", "T")
commandf3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you sure txtM.Text has the correct Onvan value? Are you sure the datatypes are correctly handled (is Onvan a char/varchar)?

Comment: Aside... [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Prefer to use one of the other `.Add(...)` overloads that specifies the exact `SqlDbType` and length/scale-and-precision.

Comment: Please use gender neutral language (guys isn't).

Comment: When you call `ExecuteNonQuery`, there are three possible outcomes: it fails and an exception is thrown, it succeeds and returns zero, or it succeeds and returns a non-zero value. Which is it in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a definitive answer but it should help you resolve it.  Use this code instead:

```
  Using commandf3 As New SqlCommand("Update Barcode set Tedad=@Tedad,Vazn=@Vazn,Ojrat=@Ojrat,Availability=@Availability where Onvan=@Onvan", connection)
        commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Onvan", txtM.Text)
        commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tedad", tedadjadid)
        commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vazn", vaznjadid)
        commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ojrat", ojratjadid)
        commandf3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Availability", "T")
        Try
            connection.Open()
            commandf3.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Handle Exception - check ex.Message for info
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
```

If the issue is that you didn't open the connection first, this may sort it.  If the connection is permanently open, maybe not.  But the catch should let you work out exactly what's happening.  If there's no error, then break the code before ExecuteNonQuery, check the value of commandf3.CommandText and verify it's really what you want, and try that command directly in SQL if needed.

Comment: Thank you Dear, I use ex.msg to see the problem. i found that datareader in my early code is open. i close it and update problem solved.